# Backups failing

Tags: deja-dup

I am using Gnome Deja-dup to backup files on my machine and getting daily messages stating that "backup failed" and nothing more. Is there a log file somewhere to look for more information about the problem?

I was able to find the duplicity log file at `~/.cache/deja-dup/duplicity.log` but it raised other questions.

- There were two copies of deja-dup active, one from Dec. 24, 2023, I do not know enough about deja-dup to know if it is safe to kill the old process. Also, I cannot tell why this old process has remained around.
- It appears that the other process may be holding lockfiles that are needed by the newer process and this is why errors are reported when the new copy of deja-dup tries to do backups. Certainly, the presence of the old process is being detected and it appears to be inhibiting the proper operation of the new process.

The following shows the report from `ps -ef` related to deja-dup:

```
jonathan@jfgdev:~$ ps -ef | grep duplicity
jonathan    5867    1963  0 Dec24 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python3.10 /usr/bin/duplicity list-current-files --time=1703402061 pydrive://google/jfgdev --no-encryption --verbosity=9 --timeout=120 --archive-dir=/home/jonathan/.cache/deja-dup --tempdir=/home/jonathan/.cache/deja-dup/tmp --log-fd=25
jonathan   48765   48139  0 11:14 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto duplicity
```

Does it look as if it is safe to kill the old process?

Comment: Can you try running `deja-dup` from the terminal and then attempting a backup to see if it gives you a specific error in the terminal's standard output?

Comment: I get the same error as when I try to run automatically. The old process is a copy of deja-dup in Python and it looks as if the newer process is a copy of duplicity.